# Compound subject or not

Tags: subjects

I guess this is too much for one subject.

> The image of a barbaric mother who commits infanticide to conceal giving birth to a bastard child avoiding stigmatization or legal punishment is reflected in this pamphlet´s case.

Is all of this 1 subject ("The image...legal punishment") or is it 1 smaller subject "The image of a barbaric mother" and a not-essential who clause " who...legal punishment".

It should be the latter, shouldn´t it?

Answer (score 1):

The subject is the whole phrase. It consists of a noun "image" and two phrases that give attributes: One is short "The" (the definite article) but the other is a very long prepositional phrase "of a barbaric mother who...punishment"

However, that is the subject. It could be re-worded to avoid this, for example using the active voice:

> The pamphlet's case reflects the image of a barbaric mother who commits infanticide ..."

Or use subject–dependent inversion:

> Reflected in this pamphlet's case is the image of a barbaric mother who commits infanticide to conceal giving birth to a bastard child, avoiding stigmatization or legal punishment.

Comment: Or use subject–dependent inversion: *Reflected in this pamphlet's case is the image of a barbaric mother who commits infanticide to conceal giving birth to a bastard child, avoiding stigmatization or legal punishment.*

Comment: Where can I learn about these things? A book or page maybe?!

Comment: active/passiv voice is not a problem. Sentence structure (in that case and probably many others) is.